# Is there a faster version of SynchronousQueue for synchronizing only 2 threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a case in my application where I need to launch an asynchronous task and then block for it to complete.  (Yes, yes, I know that it not optimal, but it's an artifact of the libraries we're using.)

Specifically, I need to call a function and pass a callback object, and the actual callback will occur on a separate thread.  But I want to wait for the callback to occur, essentially building a synchronous mechanism on top of an asynchronous one.

So my code looks something like this:

```
private static class MethodCallback implements RpcCallback<Message> {
    private Message message = null;
    private boolean done = false;
    private long started = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public synchronized void run(Message parameter) {
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
        log.debug("Got callback after {} millis", elapsed);
        this.message = parameter;
        this.done = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void await() throws ServiceException {
        while(!done && (System.currentTimeMillis() - started < MAX_WAIT_MILLIS)) {
            try {
                long remaining = (started + MAX_WAIT_MILLIS) - System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(remaining <= 0) {
                    remaining = 1;
                }
                wait(remaining);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!done) {
            String msg = String.format("Timeout: No response from async process");
            log.warn(msg);
            throw new ServiceException(msg);
        }
    }

    public Message get() {
        return message;
    }
}

public Message getMessageFromAsyncProcess() {
    MethodCallback callback = new MethodCallback();
    channel.doAsyncThing(callback);
    callback.await();
    Message result = callback.get();
    if(result == null) {
        throw new ServiceException("Error: async process did not produce a result");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, this code works perfectly well, and the application performs acceptably quickly.  But profiling has determined that `MessageCallback.run` is a performance bottleneck, presumably due to synchronization.

So as an experiment, I modified the code to use a [`SynchronousQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) instead, expecting that this would improve the performance.  But to my surprise it made it run about twice as slowly (approximately 15ms per call on average versus approximately 7ms per call for the do-it-the-hard-way version).

I could presumably hack up an alternative mechanism using either a [`Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or something like [`AtomicBoolean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html), but should I expect either of those would perform any better?

Given that I only have two threads, and I simply want one of them to wait until the other has produced a single result, is there any mechanism that will be better than what I'm doing now?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are using a Windows system which has a clock resolution of about `15 ms`. I suggest you try using `System.nanoTime()` for more accurate timings.

**The most obvious solution is to use an executor service which would only take a few lines of code as is designed to do exactly what you trying to achieve.**

You should be able to switch between threads passing a task back and forth, in about `1 - 8 us (micro-seconds)`  Even under load, you best timings should be about this time.

Note: your `wait()` method will not wake up until it can obtain a lock (after `run()` completes) This probably isn't what you intended.

Comment: What do you mean about wait()? run() completes right after calling notifyAll().

Comment: @Sergey,  The await() method takes a timeout.  This timeout will only work if the run() has not started before the timeout is reached. Once the run() has started, the timeout has no effect and the wait() method will not return until it finishes.  A more typical implementation would see the await() method return on the timeout even if the run() fails to finish in time.

Comment: Oh, now I see. You certainly have a point here, but in this case the run() method has no lengthy operations in it, it's just a callback that notifies that the library call is finished. I guess the whole point is that timeout can expire _before_ the run() is called.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I think you've hit onto an important point with `await()` having to wait to reacquire the monitor.  @Sergey is also correct that I'm more concerned with timeouts that expire *before* `run()` has started than ones that occur while `run()` is executing.  I also agree that something like `ExecutorService` combined with `Future<V>` would be simpler, but at the moment I'm at the mercy of a library that is structured around callback methods.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I'm also suspicious of a timing of about 15ms showing up, but I came up with that number by averaging the times out of ~8000 executions of realistic load under the NetBeans profiler.  It's a bit back-of-the-napkin, but I'm relatively confident that those waits are real.  Perhaps a more important reason is that 15ms is (AFAIK) the standard Windows NT quantum size.

Comment: @Daniel, its the quantum size for currentTimeMillis is 15 ms, perhaps you can remove this and avoid waiting until the bitter end. (you could busy wait the last 15 ms if that is where the error is)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, I can see nothing obvious that would make it a bottleneck.

If you are getting times like 7ms and 15ms for this, I suspect that the root cause is that you have significantly more active (runnable) threads than physical processors.  If this is the case, then the longish delays are due to waiting for a processor to become available to run a thread that has become runnable.  You might be able to improve the average delays by *reducing* the number of threads, but this might also reduce overall throughput.

Incidentally, I think that your custom synchronization code could be replaced with use of [`FutureTask`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), though I don't expect this would reduce average call times.